# Open PDF Programmatically in One Page View

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, reportviewer

I have a 2005 Reporting Services report that I display as a PDF through the report viewer control. I would like to know how I can have the PDF be viewed in the "one page at a time mode". Right now it's going to the scrollable page mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can control that since it depends on the pdf viewer application you use.